# Plot a 2d lattice in python using custom shapes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, lattice

Hi I have a 2d array of lattice locations and a 2d array that corresponds to presence or absence of a particle at the lattice locations. I want to plot the lattice it represents.

Here is the sample code:

```
size = 32
x = np.arange(size)
y = np.arange(size)
xlat1, ylat1 = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=False, indexing='ij')
# define occupancy matrix:
occ1 = np.empty([size, size])
init_rand1 = randfunc(np.shape(occ1)[0],np.shape(occ1)[1])
# set occupancy to 0 or 1:
for i in range(0,np.shape(occ1)[0]):
   for j in range(0,np.shape(occ1)[1]):
       if init_rand1[i,j] < prob_tet:
           occ1[i,j] = 0
       else:
           occ1[i,j] = 1
```

How can I plot these 0s and 1s at their corresponding lattice locations using custom shapes like circles?

Comment: So many ways, like using `plt.scatter` for example, not sure what your exact problem is here...

Comment: `plt.imshow(occ1, cmap='gray')`

Comment: @Julien i want to plot special shapes that may or may not exist at each lattice point. So there are three arrays: x and y locations and a z array which has 0 or 1 corresponding to each node of the lattice.

Comment: @Julien i have tried imshow but it produces a black and white patch over the 2d lattice area. instead i want discreet shapse maybe like a circle at every place there is occupancy = True at the lattice node